# How to get profile pictures of each contact

Tags: rest, oauth, liveconnect

I'm using the REST API from Windows Live Connect.
I can get all contacts from an user but I don't understand how to get their profile photo.

Here is the manual I'm using.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243648.aspx

I'm using the scope: `wl.basic` and in a first time sent a request to `https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/contacts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look under the details of [the user request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243648.aspx#user), it has a note that tells how to get the picture

> To get a User object by using the Live Connect REST API, make a GET
>   request to either /me, or /USER_ID.
>
> **Note  To redirect a GET call to the URL of a user's picture, you can
>   call /me/picture or /USER_ID/picture.**

Comment: I already try it but i got this error: "The provided URL is not valid. The requested resource 'picture' is not supported."

Comment: This is the url I'm using: `https://apis.live.net/v5.0/contact.0xfffff000000000000000000000000/picture`

Comment: Where is the token? From the documentation:        Request URLs must reference https://apis.live.net/v5.0/, followed by the path for the object you are working with, any parameters, and finally, the access token (represented here as ACCESS_TOKEN).

https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/albums?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: yes ofcourse I'm passing all the necessary for the authentication. with `https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/picture` it works well.

Comment: Where are you getting the ID from. The notes say: A User object's ID is not the same as a contact ID. Instead of using the ID from the ID field in the contact object response, use the user_id field from the same response.